# What is the intution behind std::set<Key,Compare,Allocator>::find() function using the '<' operator instead of '==' operator?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

Why does the find() function on a set of custom class (let's say Person) calls the inequality operator '`<`'  instead of '`==`' . To illustrate , i have the following code , and i am calling the `find` function on a set of class Person (see `test2()`) . .

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<set>
using namespace std ; 

class Person {
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &os  , const Person p) ;

string name ; 
int age;
public : 

    Person()
:name{"Unknown"}, age{0}{
    }
    Person(string name , int age )
        :name{name}, age{age}
        {
            }
    //OVERLOADED operators 
    bool operator<(const Person &rhs) const;
    bool operator ==(const Person &rhs) const;
};

bool Person::operator<(const Person &rhs) const{
    cout<<" < operator called"<<endl;
    return this->age < rhs.age;
}

bool Person::operator==(const Person &rhs)  const{
    cout<<"Equality operator"<<endl;
    return (this->age == rhs.age && this->name == rhs.name);
}

ostream & operator<<( ostream &os , const Person p ){
    os<<p.name <<":"<<p.age<<endl;
    return os;
}

template<class T>
void display(const set<T> &s1){
    for (const auto &temp : s1){
        cout<<temp <<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void test2(){
        cout<<"====================TEST2=========="<<endl;
    set<Person> stooges {
        {"Larry",2},
        {"Moe",1},
        {"Curly",3},
    };
    cout<<"Something random "<<endl;
    auto it = stooges.find(Person{"Moe",1});   //Calls the '<' operator
}

int main(){
test2();
    return 0;
}
```

I have also written the `cout` statements in the definition of overloaded operators '`<`' and '`==`' .
And the output reads :

```
====================TEST2==========
 < operator called
 < operator called
 < operator called
 < operator called
 < operator called
Something random 
 < operator called
 < operator called
 < operator called
Hit any key to continue...
```

Comment: The requirement is that elements of the keys in the set can be sorted i.e. placed consistently in some order, by comparing them according to some criterion.     It is not possible to do that, if the only means of comparison is `==`.   Consider a set with three keys, `"A"`, `"B"`, and `"C"`.   The comparisons `"A" == "B"`, `"A" == "C"`,  and `"B" == "C"` will all compare false - which gives no information at all about how to sort them into any order.   Whereas doing the comparisons `"A" < "B"`, `"A" < "C"`,  and `"B" < "C"` does give information about how to order them.

Comment: Aside from ordering, note that equivalence is a weaker condition than equality, and requiring a definition of equality would be unnecessarily restrictive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `std::find` uses equivalence not equality.  Equivalence uses `operator<` to determine if two objects `a` and `b` are the same:

```
!(a < b) && !(b < a)
```

*i.e.* if `a` isn't less than `b` and `b` isn't less than `a` then they're equivalent.

Comment: In OPs case this also means that there couldn't be more than one `Person` per age in the set. So `std::set<Person> s{{"Larry", 3}, {"Moe", 3}};` would have size 1 not 2 (since `<` does not use the name only the age) even though `!(Person{"Larry", 3} == Person{"Moe", 3})`. This is perfectly legal but it is unintuitive behavior and should be avoided sinve it can easily create bugs.

Comment: @n314159: Though this could be solved by incorporating the `name` into the comparison, to provide a total ordering. Easy to implement efficiently in modern C++ too, thanks to `std::tie` providing a zero-copy way to perform lexicographic sorting: Just replace the `operator<` return with `return std::tie(age, name) < std::tie(rhs.age, rhs.name);`. Or you just document that the class only works sanely with `std::multiset`, not `std::set`, so the equivalence of two people with the same age doesn't prevent you from storing both.